# Prove/disprove converge series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can you help me or give me a hint with this, I don't know from where to start:

prove/disprove this:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)!}=\frac{e^1+e^{-1}}{2}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what a hyperbolic trig function is?

Comment: you mean cosh x?

Comment: Yes.  Try and find the taylor series expansion of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: $e^x=\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$; what do you get when you substitute $x=1$ and $x=-1$ and add?

Comment: so I have Σ1/n! +Σ(-1)^n/n!?

Comment: @Dan: You do indeed, and you can combine that into a single summation, since these series are absolutely convergent.

Comment: Nice! thnaks!!! really help!!!

Comment: @Dan: You’re welcome!